# Jetty Websocket JSR 356 Error 403

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, websocket, jetty

let me start off by saying I am new to maven and jetty. Anyways, I have my websocket working when I'm on windows and using localhost as the websocket address. Then, I copied the code to my AWS server and changed the websocket address in the browser to the AWS DNS. When I tried to run the that, I got an error 403 (forbidden permission) and the handshake failed. Everywhere I've looked online says that a 403 error is something you manually add to your websocket server. Is there some kind of file permission thing I'm missing on the server side? Jetty says it's up and running on the server side by the way.

Comment: What happens if you change that AWS DNS to 127.0.0.1? Does it works

Comment: Well, I'm no longer getting 403. Now, I'm getting this error with using that. WebSocket connection failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: I don't think that can be right anyways. I want jetty running on the server not the local machine. 127.0.0.1 is localhost of the browser's machine

Answer (score 0):

`403 Forbidden` is a response seen during a HTTP/1.1 Connection upgrade to Websocket and the `/origin/` information isn't sane.

See [RFC6455: Origin Considerations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-10.2) for more details about what the websocket spec says.

Jetty's implementation will not automatically issue a `403 Forbidden` on its own, the only way you'll see that out of Jetty server is if your custom [`WebSocketCreator`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/servlet/WebSocketCreator.html) has chosen to use [`sendForbidden()`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/servlet/ServletUpgradeResponse.html#sendForbidden-java.lang.String-)

Comment: I haven't told my websocket server to check the origin, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: any intermediary system can perform the origin check as well.  Don't assume its the Jetty server returning this response to you.

Comment: After spending pretty much the entire day researching this, I think the problem comes from AWS, but I wasn't able to really get further than that. Do you know what it could be? I already have port 8080 open on the security group.